# Telerik MVC DatePicker Doesn't Bind to Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker, telerik-mvc

I am trying to use Telerik MVC DatePicker in my project. Here is the situation:

1. I have a model which have :

   ```
   ...
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   public System.Nullable<DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
   ...
   ```
2. My ProjectCreate view has strong type of the model given above
3. Between

   ```
   @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { Class="ym-form ym-columnar" }))
   {
   ...
   }
   ```

   I have:

   ```
   @(Html.Telerik().DateTimePickerFor(c => c.EndDate)
                   .Name("EndDatePicker")
   ```
4. Within my action

   ```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
   public ActionResult ProjectCreate(ProjectView view)
   {
   ...
   }
   ```

the

```
    view.EndDate
```

value is always null whichever date I choose.

I have googled a lot but couldn't find what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are setting the `Name` of your datepicker. You don't need that when using `DatePickerFor`:

```
@(Html.Telerik().DateTimePickerFor(c => c.EndDate))
```